# r creating a summary table of how often a type is used

Tags: r

I have a data frame `A` with `name` and `type`.

```
name    aa  tt  gg  cc  aa  at  ag  ac

 type    3   2   4   3   2   2   3   3
```

How can I create a new ranked data.frame `B` with `type` and a count of the number of times 
the type occurred in data.frame `A`?

```
count   4   3   1   

type    3   2   4
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is the `table()` function. For your data:

```
dat <- data.frame(name = c("aa","tt","gg","cc","aa","at","ag","ac"),
                  type = c(3,2,4,3,2,2,3,3))
```

it gives:

```
> (tab <- with(dat, table(type)))
type
2 3 4 
3 4 1
```

Now we just need to sort it:

```
> sort(tab, decreasing = TRUE)
type
3 2 4 
4 3 1
```

These steps can be combined, of course:

```
> with(dat, sort(table(type), decreasing = TRUE))
type
3 2 4 
4 3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Two other approaches that may be faster:

```
rev(sort(tapply(dat$type, dat$type, length)))

x <- do.call('data.frame', (rle(sort(dat$type)))); x[order(-x$lengths), ]
```

EDIT:
Nope on Gavin's data set the table approach he proposes is the fastest (tested using microbenchmark on a win7 machine):

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr     min      lq  median       uq      max
1    RLE 614.452 650.376 669.971 713.3605 104852.7
2  TABLE 562.664 586.691 607.453 645.9440 128596.5
3 TAPPLY 585.525 626.115 643.144 689.0995 118123.8
```

Comment: +1 nice alternatives. I suspect **data.table** would be best bet for large problems however.